# PHP Session not clearing?

Tags: php, session

I am using PHP sessions for a tool I have created. It allows for you to resume a previous session you may have started that is stored in the database. All that functionality is working as intended.

However, I provide a link that says "Create New Session" and point it to a PHP page that contains this code:

```
<?php
session_start();
session_destroy();
$_SESSION = array();
unset($_SESSION);
header('Location: wizard.php');
?>
```

Now, when it redirects back to wizard.php, I have it printing out all session details and it still contains information from the previous session.

Is there something I am missing here?

Wizard.php starts with session_create(); so I would assume as soon as it redirected it would create a new session ID and all which isnt happening.

Thanks for any info

Comment: You need to unset it BEFORE destroing it...

Comment: I just changed that and wizard.php still contains the same session_id that it had before running that block of code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php
    // Initialize the session.
    // If you are using session_name("something"), don't forget it now!
    session_start();

    // Unset all of the session variables.
    $_SESSION = array();

    // If it's desired to kill the session, also delete the session cookie.
    // Note: This will destroy the session, and not just the session data!
    if (isset($_COOKIE[session_name()])) {
        setcookie(session_name(), '', time()-42000, '/');
    }

    // Finally, destroy the session.
    session_destroy();

    header('Location: wizard.php');
?>
```

Taken from: [**session_destroy Example 1**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-destroy.php)

Comment: Thank you, I think it was something to do with the cookie not being cleared as well. This works perfectly.